# systemd service redirect stdout to custom filename

Tags: service, filenames, systemd

I am working with systemd services in order to start an application. Stdout should be redirected to a file containing the current date (when the service was started). Logging to a file works fine, however, I don't know how to provide the date for the filename within the service. Any ideas?

```
...
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/mybin
StandardOutput=file:/my/path/<filename should contain date>.log
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

systemd cannot generate the file name dynamically. But you can use `bash` redirection and `date` to create such a logfile.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/mybin >/my/path/filename-$(date %%y-%%d-%%m).log"
```

Comment: Thanks for making clear that there is no way to handle the filename generation dynamically. However, your workaround also fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same needs and I have found a nice solution for me. It works well. Hope it can help you too.

**1. Create an script.**

You must put the script under `/usr/bin`. It's `/usr/bin/ruoyi-gen.sh` for me.

**2. Add below contents.**

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /root/xf-service/ruoyi-modules-gen-2.3.0.jar > /root/xf-service/ilogs/modules-gen-`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.log 2>&1 &
```

Make the script executable -> `chmod +x /usr/bin/ruoyi-gen.sh`.

**3. Add service description**

Run `vi /etc/systemd/system/ruoyi-gen.service`, Add desciption like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=ruoyi-gen

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruoyi-gen.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**4. Reload all systemd service files**

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

**5.Start your service**

```
systemctl start ruoyi-gen
```

It works on CentOS 7.